# How to get signature length from signature body in Crypto++ ECDSA

Tags: c++, crypto++, ecdsa

I use Crypto++ (libcrypto++ 1.11) to embed JWT in my application. I made methods to sign and verify messages with `CryptoPP::ECDSA<CryptoPP::ECP, CryptoPP::SHA256>` algorithm (with `secp256r1` curve). Tokens for verification can come from the outer world, so I need to verify token contents (textual data) signature knowing the public key.

The problem is that Crypto++ can cause SegFault on invalid signatures, which gives me a lot of pain in my web server.

I hoped that signatures in BER format (default serialization format in the library) have fixed length, so all I need is to compare the length of signature with some constant. However, I found out larger contents enables larger signatures, so a deeper approach is needed.

```
bool ES256Verifier::Verify(const std::string& data,
                           const std::string& signature) {
    bool result = false;
    try {
      CryptoPP::StringSource ss(
          signature + data, true,
          new CryptoPP::SignatureVerificationFilter(
              verifier_,
              new CryptoPP::ArraySink((byte*)&result, sizeof(result))));
    } catch (const CryptoPP::BERDecodeErr& err) {
      LOG_WARNING() << "Signature `" << signature << "` has invalid (non-BER) format";
    } catch (const CryptoPP::Exception& ex) {
      LOG_WARNING() << "Signature verification has failed: " << ex.what();
    }
    return result;
}
```

Verifier `verifier_` is initialized correctly (and verifies tokens successfully apart from SegFaults), but given `data = ""` and `signature = ""`, for example, I always get SegFault:

```
__memmove_avx_unaligned_erms 0x00007fb4b9da6b38
CryptoPP::ArraySink::Put2(unsigned char const*, unsigned long, int, bool) 0x00007fb4ba414fb2
CryptoPP::BufferedTransformation::ChannelPut2(std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&, unsigned char const*, unsigned long, int, bool) 0x00007fb4ba3acedc
CryptoPP::StringStore::CopyRangeTo2(CryptoPP::BufferedTransformation&, unsigned long long&, unsigned long long, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&, bool) const 0x00007fb4ba414e02
CryptoPP::BufferedTransformation::Peek(unsigned char*, unsigned long) const 0x00007fb4ba3ad74a
CryptoPP::Integer::Decode(CryptoPP::BufferedTransformation&, unsigned long, CryptoPP::Integer::Signedness) 0x00007fb4ba45885c
CryptoPP::Integer::Decode(unsigned char const*, unsigned long, CryptoPP::Integer::Signedness) 0x00007fb4ba458c16
CryptoPP::DL_VerifierBase<CryptoPP::ECPPoint>::InputSignature pubkey.h:1560
CryptoPP::SignatureVerificationFilter::LastPut(unsigned char const*, unsigned long) 0x00007fb4ba4159a0
CryptoPP::FilterWithBufferedInput::PutMaybeModifiable(unsigned char*, unsigned long, int, bool, bool) 0x00007fb4ba418107
CryptoPP::BufferedTransformation::ChannelPut2(std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&, unsigned char const*, unsigned long, int, bool) 0x00007fb4ba3acedc
CryptoPP::BufferedTransformation::TransferMessagesTo2(CryptoPP::BufferedTransformation&, unsigned int&, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&, bool) 0x00007fb4ba3ad8fa
CryptoPP::BufferedTransformation::TransferAllTo2(CryptoPP::BufferedTransformation&, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&, bool) 0x00007fb4ba3adb21
CryptoPP::SourceTemplate<CryptoPP::StringStore>::PumpAll2 filters.h:1238
CryptoPP::Source::PumpAll filters.h:1182
CryptoPP::Source::SourceInitialize filters.h:1215
CryptoPP::StringSource::StringSource filters.h:1271
jwt::signature::algorithm::ES256Verifier::Verify es256_verifier.cpp:40
ES256_SignatureTest_Test::TestBody es256_test.cpp:29
...
```

So, is there a way to look at the data and signature and decide if this particular combination is going to cause SegFault due to invalid signature length?

Comment: The sample I used was taken from [wiki](https://www.cryptopp.com/wiki/Elliptic_curve_digital_signature_algorithm#Complete_Example), and no, SignatureVerificationFilter does not change a thing.

Comment: looks like its probably putting more than a single byte, try putting a breakpoint on `CryptoPP::ArraySink::Put2` and see how many times it is called and how many bytes its trying to write?

Comment: If you provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), then I can probably provide a thorough answer. I'm guessing you are using a ElGamal-like scheme, so the [binary] size of the signature is 2*field-element-size since there is an `r` and `s`. There's also some variability near *"r and s"* because it can be a simple concatenation of `r || s` or it can be DER-encoded.

Comment: An example of the two ways to present `r` and `s` is given at [Elliptic Curve Digital Signature Algorithm | OpenSSL and Java Interop](https://www.cryptopp.com/wiki/Elliptic_Curve_Digital_Signature_Algorithm#OpenSSL_and_Java_Interop) on the Crypto++ wiki. It shows both formats because the signature has to be converted from DER to P1363 for Crypto++ to use.

Comment: @jww Sorry for the silince, I will make MCVE on Sunday, currently it is embedded in custom code base. It seems that 32 bytes are read anyway in DL_VerifierBase without any check, thus checking that signature is at least 32 bytes solves particular ""/"" issue. I will make a couple experiments on Sunday with gdb on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's some sample code to determine the signature length using the Field Element, Signer and Verifier. The first output prints the element length and `r||s` length because `r||s` is the signature in P1363 format.

The second and third output just print the result of `SignatureLength()`. Your program should reject a signature shorter than `SignatureLength()`. There is no sense in even trying to verify a short signature since it is no good.

*Note well*: this only work for the `DL_*` signature schemes (based on discrete logs). It does not apply to `TF_*` signature schemes (based on trapdoor functions).

```cxx
#include "cryptlib.h"
#include "eccrypto.h"
#include "osrng.h"
#include "oids.h"

#include <iostream>

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    using namespace CryptoPP;
    AutoSeededRandomPool prng;

    ///// Element
    DL_GroupParameters_EC<ECP> params(ASN1::secp256r1());

    unsigned int elemLength = params.GetCurve().GetField().MaxElementByteLength();
    std::cout << "Element length: " << elemLength << std::endl;
    std::cout << "r||s length: " << 2*elemLength << std::endl;

    ///// Signer
    ECDSA<ECP, SHA256>::Signer signer;
    signer.AccessKey().Initialize(prng, params);

    unsigned int signerLength = signer.SignatureLength();
    std::cout << "Signer signature length: " << signerLength << std::endl;

    ///// Verifier
    ECDSA<ECP, SHA256>::Verifier verifier(signer);

    unsigned int verifierLength = verifier.SignatureLength();
    std::cout << "Verifier signature length: " << verifierLength << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Running the program results in the following.

```
$ ./test.exe
Element length: 32
r||s length: 64
Signer signature length: 64
Verifier signature length: 64
```

And if you switch curves to `ASN1::secp521r1()`, then running the program results in the following.

```
$ ./test.exe
Element length: 66
r||s length: 132
Signer signature length: 132
Verifier signature length: 132
```